# How would a student express that they are not having the first class today and that the classes start with the second?

Tags: expressions

Imagine that something happened to the schedule (e.g. teacher got an emergency and had to leave for the day) and now the student has to come to classes later, how do they express that it's the *second* class they are coming to today, not the first one?

In Russian they say "[to come] by the second one" ("[прийти] ко второй [паре]") and I couldn't find the proper way to express the same in English: "to come by the second class" just sounds off to me.

Comment: If you're starting the day with the second class, that's not complicated to understand.

Comment: The first class was cancelled. That means there was no class, not that you skipped it.

Comment: "Please skip the first class, which was cancelled, and keep the appointment with the second class on your schedule."

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you mean when you say *the second class today*.  Do you mean the instructor teaches more than one class per day and you will now go to the second class taught by that instructor?  Or do you mean that the instructor has rescheduled the first class to a time later in the day?  Or do you mean the first class is cancelled and so your day will begin with whatever your second class is?  In other words, how many classes was the instructor teaching per day?  If the instructor teaches 3+ classes per day, why wouldn't you come to the third or fourth, why the second?

Comment: The normal thing would I think be to say "Go to the 11 o'clock class" or whenever the second class is.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be something like, "My first class today was cancelled, so I'm starting the day with my second class."